# BlogEngine Compile Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, blogengine.net, blog-engine

I'm getting three similar errors when trying to compile a BlogEngine 2.6 Web Application Project:

**In VS intellisense:**

```
the type 'RazorHelpers' exists in both 'App_Code' and BlogEngine.Web.dll
```

**Compile error:**

```
Error    27  The type 'RazorHelpers' exists in both 
             'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Nordic\Bin\BlogEngine.Web.dll' and 'App_Code'  
              c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Nordic\themes\RazorHost\CommentView.ascx   25
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I had to abandon the 2.6 WAP version and switch to the Website version, then migrate all of my design and code customizations.

Answer (score 1):

In WAP projects you want to make sure you don't use the app_code directory because classes within that directory will get compiled twice (once in the code-behind and again at runtime) unless you exclude the file from the WAP project.

You could also try renaming the app_code directory to something else.

Comment: Apparently, it is actually a WAP and I was opening it as a Web site project. However the problem still persisted. +1 as what you say is technically correct :-)